# Permission Denied when deploying with Jenkins to Apache-owned directory

Tags: wordpress, jenkins, permissions

### Background

At work we recently started using Jenkins CI for our Java code. We liked it so much, we wanted to use it for some PHP projects and some WordPress themes that we maintain as well.

### The problem

I have set up Jenkins to run a gulp task to build the theme, which works fine. Then I have a deploy job that removes the old theme and moves the new code in place. This is where the problem lies. I have a bash script that runs in the deploy job like so:

```
whoami
mv /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/backups/theme/$(date '+%F')_$BUILD_NUMBER-backup_my-theme
mv $JENKINS_HOME/workspace/Build_MyTheme/build/my-theme /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes
```

When this runs, I get into the permission issues. Lots of "Permission Denied" errors. The `whoami` command prints off `tomcat`. Then the commands after that, like I mentioned, throw permission denied errors for the moving of the folder (whose parent folder, and self, are owned by `apache`). As far as I know, in order for WordPress themes to have handy features like updating itself, and plugins to be able to update and delete; the themes and plugins need to be owned by the `apache` user.

I am new at Jenkins CI, in fact another Developer set it up in Java. So I could be doing something wrong, but I think the main problem is the permission issues. **How would you overcome permission errors where `tomcat` has to manipulate files owned by `apache`?**

### What I've tried

I have tried adding both apache and tomcat to a group called `webusers`, but I still got permission denied errors when trying to manipulate the files with Jenkins.

I have tried changing the owner of the files to `tomcat`:

[image: permissions of the wp-content directory]

This is the `wp-content` directory. As you can see, or maybe not because its so pixelated, that the plugins and themes folders are owned by tomcat and in the webusers directory. This *works* but with a major downside:

[image: Cannot manipulate things from WordPress dashboard]

This is a major drawback, as it creates a bad user experience.

I have also tried making apache the owner, and using the group (previously created), then WordPress works, but Jenkins fails to deploy:

[image: non-working permissions]

I'm just at a loss here, I have googled many times on the topics of "WordPress and Jenkins," "deplying WordPress with Jenkins," etc. As many varieties as I can think of. I have even gone to [the Jenkins Documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Use+Jenkins) for help, but it refrences Drupal tutorials.

I [read somewhere](https://yakiloo.com/setup-apache-and-jenkins/) that you can deploy an Apache version of Jenkins, which may work for our PHP projects, but **is it really best practice to have an instance of Jenkins per language?**

Any help would be fantastic. Thank you ahead of time.